# download source of jstack.exe (tool for making jvm tradedump)

Tags: java, oracle, jstack

I've looked on oracle site, googled, but haven't found any download link. only doc and tutorials

Could somebody share the download link, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `jstack` command is part of the JDK. You can find it very quick and easy by checking out the JDK source code: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/jdk.jcmd/share/classes/sun/tools/jstack/JStack.java

Comment: found it in bin folder of JDK. thanks